# Forecasting stock prices with ARCH Model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, garch

I am pretty confused about the ARCH model and forecasting of stock prices / stock returns. I have read some literature about forecasting with different models (AR,MA,ARMA) and i get the concept of them and I also implemented them on a time series (of a stock price in R). Now i want to do forecasting with a ARCH model but all I can find in the literature is the forecasting of volatility of a time series but not on forecasting of the time series itself.
Is it even possible to do such a forecast with the ARCH model? And if so can you explain to me how i should approach?

Comment: so you want to assume the conditional mean is changing as well as the conditional variance? and you want help with the coding? I know the `rugarch` helps with fitting ARMA + GARCH models

Comment: My problem is, that I dont know how to compute the forecasts. For example in the AR(1) model it is Y(t)=a(0)+a(1)*Y(t-1)+e(t). For the first Forecast I simply switch the index and get Y(t+1)=a(0)+a(1)*Y(t)+e(t). But i dont know how I get these equations for the forecast in an ARCH model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["GARCH forecasting in R: constant mean forecast!"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301458/forecasting-levels-through-garch-model) and ["Forecasting levels through GARCH model"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154770/garch-forecasting-in-r-constant-mean-forecast). If these are not enough, check out the other questions tagged with [tag:garch] and [tag:volatility-forecasting] (and [tag:arima], [tag:autoregressive], [tag:moving-average], [tag:forecasting] and [tag:finance]) to find out more.

Comment: ["What is the difference between GARCH and ARMA?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41509/what-is-the-difference-between-garch-and-arma) can also be helpful.

Comment: I read all the links you posted and I get from them, that I need a ARMA-GARCH model to forecast my time series. The way I understand the concept of this model is, that it is very similiar to the ARMA model with the difference, that e(t) isn't a N(0,1) random variable but it is e(t)=sigma(t)*Z(t) where Z(t) is N(0,1). And sigma^2(t) can be computed based on the GARCH order. Am I right with that or have I missunderstood the model?

Comment: Yes, you have understood that correctly.

Comment: So the formula looks like this: