# Forecasting monthly demand for automobiles given historical daily data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, state-space-models

I am trying to predict demand of Automobiles at dealer and Variant level. I have 2 year, 2 months daily sales data. I need to predict demand at monthly level based on daily data for Enquiry.[image: Dummy data for forecasting]

Just to make it more clear, if I am on 5th of March 2017 so based on enquiries so far, earlier sales data etc. I need to predict total sales of March. Again, if I am on 15th of March so based on total enquiries till 15th, sales so far in month (in last 30 days etc.), I need to predict total sales for the month of March.

I have tried regression using lagged variables like total sales in last 30 days, total enquiries in last 30 days etc, but results are very poor. I have tried `auto.arima` with exogenous variable but results are not very good.

Sales are high on weekends and on March and October (Festival season in India).
I have few questions:

1. What should be my approach?
2. What are the other techniques I can use?
3. I had built ARIMA at day of month level but it gives me only 26 data points. (12*2+) 31 models in total and it does not take care of weekend effect. Can   this be improved?
4. Can some state space model be used here?

Comment: Please let me know if i am not cogent enough or some explanation is required.

Comment: maybe this site help:http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269503/predictions-remain-same-for-arima-model/269560#269560 and http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/machine-learning-features-engineering-from-date-time-data?rq=1#  lagged variables always overfiting, so try some aggregate on it.

Comment: Above site, I post an answer about how to construct the aggregate feature on the time-dependent features.